# Perfrom a multiple linear regression in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps, statistics, regression-analysis

I'm attempting to run a multiple linear regression in Google Sheets, but the only add-on I can find to do this (XLMiner) has been disabled by Google pending review. It also looks like the review process has taken over 8 months, so I don't anticipate it will be available anytime soon.

Are there alternative add-ons, or a formula I could create in the sheet itself in order to perform a multiple linear regression?

Answer (score 0):

##### LINEST formula

One option is to use Google Sheets' embedded ­`LINEST` function, take a look at [this article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094249?hl=en) for more information.

However, `LINEST` doesn't automatically do standard scaling of the input data, nor does it support train-test splits and cross-validation, all of which are considered good practices. Hence there's also a second option.

##### TableTorch add-on for Google Sheets

TableTorch support linear regressions with advanced options like standard scaling, cross-validation, label transformation, stratified sampling, etc., its UI allows to quickly estimate model's quality metrics and insert a prediction column that is usable on the new data. Here are a few links:

1. [Install TableTorch add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/tabletorch/347211125985) for Google Sheets using Google Workspace Marketplace.
2. [TableTorch walk-through article on linear regressions](https://www.gaujasoft.com/tabletorch/docs/linear-regression/).
3. [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMQRSfnATYY) on using the Linear Regression function of TableTorch.